# Why does .done() require an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this work:

```
$.ajax({ url: urlIn, dataType: 'json', cache: false })
     .done( function( data ) { doStuff( data ) });
```

But not this:

```
$.ajax({ url: urlIn, dataType: 'json', cache: false })
     .done( doStuff( data ) );
```

That second one "data" is not defined. It took me a while to realize that was the problem. But its mysterious to me why it works like that.

Comment: you can just put doStuff. The function must read data though.

Comment: I can never understand why people downmod questions just because they are basic. Especially when the questions merits a bunch of really clear answers with tons of upvotes.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista Sometimes SO no more really makes sense... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685978/heuristically-figuring-out-whether-im-running-ipad1-or-ipad2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By calling `.done( doStuff( data ) )`, you're actually **invoking** the `doStuff` function **immediately**. What gets passed to the `done` function is its **return value**, which is equal to `undefined` in your case.

Now, if the `doStuff` function were to return a function itself, that returned function could then be called as a callback by `doStuff`.

What you want to do instead is pass the function as a value without invoking it right away:

```
$.ajax({ url: urlIn, dataType: 'json', cache: false }).done(doStuff);
```

Answer (score 6):

Because those aren't the same thing.

This is a function definition:

```
function( data ) { doStuff( data ) }
```

This is a function *invocation*:

```
doStuff( data )
```

It's telling the code to execute `doStuff(data)` *now* and use its *result* as the callback function.  Since `data` doesn't exist yet, that won't work.  (And if `doStuff` doesn't return a function, that won't work.)

The analogous version is simply this:

```
$.ajax({ url: urlIn, dataType: 'json', cache: false })
 .done( doStuff );
```

`data` will be passed in automatically.

Comment: +1 for clear distinction between *definition* and *invocation*.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. It just requires **function reference**, and **not calling a function**. Anonymous function (`function(){}`) would be correct function reference, so as `doStuff`. But by doing `doStuff()`, you are calling this function directly and you can't use `doStuff` as you need to pass parameters. So you should use `function( data ) { doStuff( data ) }`.

Answer (score 1):

It does not require an anonymous function. You do have it pass it a function reference though.  So, in your example, this would work just fine:

```
$.ajax({ url: urlIn, dataType: 'json', cache: false })
     .done( doStuff );
```

What you were doing was calling `doStuff(data)` immediately and passing the return value of that to `.done()` which was likely not a function reference.  You must pass a function reference (without the parens - because the parens cause it to execute immediately).

This is a very common mistake.  Functions without the parens are a reference to that function that can then be called later.  Functions with the parens are executed immediately and the return value from executing the function is passed instead.